# Google hangout / telephone / voip input to web app

Tags: angularjs, web, voip, google-hangouts

I am currently building a web application and was exploring if there is a way to parse an incoming voip call information.

For e.g.: I have a list of contacts with phone numbers on my page. when I receive a call on my hangout in that browser, I need to parse the caller's phone number and search for that phone number in the list and display that contact details. I am not tied to Google Hangouts. Any similar libraries / frameworks are fine. The application I am building uses AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

Google has published a Google Hangout API for integrating into external applications. In your particular case, I would look at the [gapi.hangout.telephone](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.telephone)

Without knowing exactly how you want to implement a solution, something as simple as call state could be written like this:

```
    gapi.hangout.telephone.onCallInitiated.add(callInitiatedEventHandler);

    myCall = gapi.hangout.telephone.beginCall(phoneNumber.number);    

    myCall.onCallStateChanged.add(callStateChangedEventHandler);
        function callStateChangedEventHandler(callStateData){                                 

          console.log("call state changed to:");
          console.log(callStateData.newState);
          if (callStateData.newState == gapi.hangout.telephone.CallStateData.USER_REJECTED_CALL){
          // The user hungup
          }
        }
```